# Flickr json feed with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I tried to have the Flickr feed on making an SPA (single page application). That works pretty well. I just have some problems putting my elements on a good from. I mean, with the generated code, instead of geting the image surrounded by "p", I get :

```
<p></p>
<img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/702/22578264723_5baef149b4_m.jpg">
<p></p>
```

And that's my code :

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JSON Flickr with JQuery</title>
  <style>
    img {
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="images"></div>



  <script>
    //$("<table><tbody>").appendTo('#images');
    (function() {
      var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
      //var flickerAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json";

      $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {

          tagmode: "any",
          format: "json"
        })
        .done(function(data) {


            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {

                $("<p>").appendTo('#images');
                $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
                $("</p><p><a href=\"" + item.link + "\">" + item.title + "</a></p>").appendTo('#images');
                $("<p>by <a href=\"" + "https://www.flickr.com/people/" + item.author_id + "\">" + item.author + "</a></p>").appendTo('#images');
                $("<p>Tags : " + item.tags + "</p>").appendTo('#images');
                $("<hr>").appendTo('#images');

              }

            );
          }

        );
    })();
    //$("</tbody></table>").appendTo('#images');
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Would have an idea with "p" or "tr" & "td" ? I think the problem is the way I am using appendTo() method.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you're appending an open element, the browser closes it for you so that the DOM remains valid. You need to save it as a variable and then append the variable once everything has been added.

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    var $append;
    $append += "<p>";
    $append += "<img src=\"" + item.media.m + "\"/>";
    $append += "</p><p><a href=\"" + item.link + "\">" + item.title + "</a></p>";
    $append += "<p>by <a href=\"" + "https://www.flickr.com/people/" + item.author_id + "\">" + item.author + "</a></p>";
    $append += "<p>Tags : " + item.tags + "</p>";
    $append += "<hr>";
    $('#images').append($append);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cameronjonesweb/pbz7cm0p/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that works better now. I just got "undifined", so I had to initialize `var $append="";`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer, that worked pretty well, I just had to initialize `var $append="";` since I was getting "undifined" on the top of every image. I've also replaced Ps with TRs and TDs. Here is the final code :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JSON Flickr with JQuery</title>
  <style>
    img {
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="images"></div>



  <script>

    (function() {
      var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

      $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {

          tagmode: "any",
          format: "json"
        })
        .done(function(data) {


            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var $append="";
                $append += "<tr><td>";
                $append += "<img src=\"" + item.media.m + "\"/>";
                $append += "</td></tr><tr><td><a href=\"" + item.link + "\">" + item.title + "</a> ";
                $append += " by <a href=\"" + "https://www.flickr.com/people/" + item.author_id + "\">" + item.author + "</a></td></tr>";
                $append += "<tr><td>Tags : " + item.tags + "</td></tr>";
                $append += "<tr><td><hr></hr></td></tr>";
                $('#images').append($append);

              }

            );
          }

        );
    })();

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```